# Why are source control systems still mostly backed with files?

Tags: version-control

It seems that more source control systems still use files as the means of storing the version data.  Vault and TFS use Sql Server as their data store, which I would think would be better for data consistency as well as speed.

So why is it that SVN, I believe GIT, CVS, etc still use the file system as essentially a database,  (I ask this question as we had our SVN server just corrupt itself during a normal commit) instead of using actual database software (MSSQL, Oracle, Postgre, etc)?

EDIT:  I think another way of asking my question is "why do VCS developers roll their own structured data storage system instead of using an exisiting one?"

Comment: What do you think most databases use as their basic backing? Most use files (a few use direct access to hard disks, however). You can have all the features of a database by using "just files".

Comment: @JoachimSauer Fair point, though of course you'd have to create a database yourself then. Which is silly if your desired feature set is close to the ones of existing solutions and don't have very good reasons to not use any of those.

Comment: Until persistent fast memory becomes a reality, the persistence afforded by disk drives (hence files) is the only real alternative.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes, I realize that, but DBM systems have ways to ensure that nothing inconsistent gets into the database.  Unless these file based repositories are using something like Transactional NTSF, there's still a possiblity of being corrupt.  And I trust a real database more than I do a set of developers essentially re-inventing the wheel, since I think we can agree that source control systems require data integrity.

Comment: @delnan  This is EXACTLY my point. It seems like SCMs like SVN have data storage requirements that traditional DBMS' have already provided a solution for.

Comment: @Andy And those requirements are?

Comment: @delnan Transactional support and internal consistency.  We are now restoring our SVN repository from tape b/c the SVN server didn't properly write to all the files it was supposed to.  Also searching huge volumes of data.  My point is, why try an re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Every major operating system comes with a file system built in.  All these file systems have the same basic functionality (files, folders, persistance of same).  Basically, a database is one extra dependency that the end-user needs to install and keep updated.  Source control isn't most people's primary business (unless you are sourceforge or github).  VC is often installed on servers through the command line by the newest member of the team.  Ease of installation and setup is important.

Comment: A sensible question, already git uses a single root directory, not in every subdirectory a .cvs. Actually I would rather use java _(impossible)_ - rather than C - with an embedded database like H2. However git can use hugely more disk space than the actual sources. Some elder people here might remember Visual SourceSafe and it infamity for getting corrupted.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

TL;DR: Few version control systems use a database because it isn't necessary.

As a question for a question answer, why wouldn't they?  What benefits do "real" database systems offer over a file system in this context?

Consider that revision control is mostly keeping track of a little metadata and a lot of text diffs.  Text is not stored in databases more efficiently, and indexability of the contents isn't going to be a factor.

Lets presume that Git (for argument's sake) used a BDB or SQLite DB for its back-end to store data.  What would be more reliable about that?  Anything that could corrupt simple files can also corrupt the database (since that's also a simple file with a more complex encoding).

From the programmer paradigm of not optimizing unless its necessary, if the revision control system is fast enough and works reliably enough, why change the entire design to use a more complex system?

Comment: TLDR? You answer was twice as long and the question was real short as it is!

Comment: @Brad The three words following the `TL;DR` are the abridged version of the answers, not a statement that the question is too long and he didn't read it before answering.

Comment: I suggest you try something like Vault that actually does use a database.  You get revision history faster, Vault has a Find in Files feature (which I believe you can do against an older revision as well), oh and I'd think that Sql Server does a better job ensuring data integrety than SVN.  SVN developers can try and build something that ensure that, but like encryption, isn't this one of those things better left to experts?

Comment: @Andy Mercurial also has "grep in history", and git likely has it as well. It's also lightning fast already. As for leaving things to expert: The people who develop VCSs *are* experts.

Comment: To continue what @delnan said, git was designed by someone who wanted really high quality revision control for a very large code base and actually uses such a product every day.  That its fast and functional the way it is is a function of that need.

Comment: @delnan ah yes. that interpretation makes more sense! I thought it was funny. I guess I've seen it both ways.

Comment: @delnan I don't really have any experience in DVCS, so I wasn't aware they provided fast searching.  SVN however is horrid for trying to search history.

Comment: Just want to add in that I do see your point; if VCS writes bad data, it doesn't matter if its writing that data to a file or database.  The flip side though is that file based repos probably are writing to more than one file at a time and normally there's no transactional support for that so if one file writes but another fails, your VCS is now corrupt, vs mutiple table writes within a database transaction will commit for fail as a unit.  I feel as though a group of devs building database software has more experience with this than the people writing SVN... but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @Andy its not hard to do things in a fs like `diff > newdiff.tmp && mv old.diff old-date.diff && mv newdiff.tmp old.diff` and avoid corruption issues most of the time anyway.

Comment: Your choice of git "for argument's sake" is an important point here:  git has a very good model for writing its objects, but many tools don't.  With git, if the computer is powered off in the middle of a commit, you'll have written some of the objects to the filesystem and they'll merely be unreachable.  With other VCSs, you may have appended the changes to half the files (and confusion ensues.)  You could argue that other version control tools are poorly designed (and you'd be right), but when you're writing a VCS, it's a lot easier to just use a SQL transaction and let it do the right thing.

Comment: And yet, for argument's sake @EdwardThomson I'd never assume that a SQL transaction is done properly either.  I've seen a great many bits of database code that are not in fact any more transaction safe than whimsy.

Comment: I think your TL;DR needs work. "Because it is necessary" Because what is unecessary? Because files are unecessary? Because a database is unecessary? I wouldn't really know the essence of what you're trying to say if all I read was the TL;DR.

Comment: @mikebabcock: fair point.

Comment: I would much rather have source backed by the file system than a DB.  A DB adds too much indirection.

Comment: -1 *"Lets presume that Git used a BDB or SQLite DB for its back-end to store data. What would be more reliable about that? Anything that could corrupt simple files can also corrupt the database."* What in the world did I just read... are you familiar with databases at all? Does "ACID" ring a bell?

Answer (score 27):

You seem to be making a lot of assumptions, possibly based on your experience with SVN and CVS.

#### Git and Mercurial are basically like SVN and CVS

Comparing git and CVS is like comparing an iPad and an Atari. CVS was created [back when dinoaurs roamed the Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System#History_and_status). Subversion is basically an improved version of CVS. Assuming that modern version control systems like git and Mercurial work like them makes very little sense.

#### A relational database is more efficient than a single-purpose database

Why? Relational databases are *really* complicated, and may not be as efficient as single-purpose databases. Some differences off the top of my head:

- Version control systems don't need complicated locking, since you can't do multiple commits at the same time anyway.
- Distributed version control systems need to be very extremely space efficient, since the local database is a full copy of the repo.
- Version control systems only need to look up data in a couple specific ways (by author, by revision ID, sometimes full-text search). Making your own database that can handle author/revision ID searches is trivial and full-text searches aren't very fast in any relational database I've tried.
- Version control systems need to work on multiple platforms. This makes it harder to use a database that needs to be installed and running as a service (like MySQL or PostgreSQL).
- Version control systems on your local machine only need to be running when you're doing something (like a commit). Leaving a service like MySQL running *all the time* just in case you want to do a commit is wasteful.
- For the most part, version control systems never want to delete history, just append to it. That may lead to different optimizations, and different methods of protecting integrity.

#### Relational databases are safer

Again, why? You seem to assuming that because data is stored in files, version control systems like git and Mercurial don't have [atomic commits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_commit#Revision_Control), but they do. Relational databases *also* store their databases as files. It's notable here that CVS *doesn't* do atomic commits, but that's likely because it's from the dark ages, not because they don't use relational databases.

There's also the issue of protecting the data from corruption once it's in the database, and again the answer is the same. If the filesystem is corrupted, then it doesn't matter which database you're using. If the filesystem isn't corrupted, then your database engine might be broken. I don't see why a version control database would be more prone to this than a relational database.

I would argue that distributed version control systems (like git and Mercurial) are better for protecting your database than centralized version control, since you can restore the entire repo from any clone. So, if your central server spontaneously combusts, along with all of your backups, you can restore it by running `git init` on the new server, then `git push` from *any developer's machine*.

#### Reinventing the wheel is bad

Just because you *can* use a relational database for any storage problem doesn't mean you *should*. Why do you use configuration files instead of a relational database? Why store images on the filesystem when you could store the data in a relational database? Why keep your code on the filesystem when you could store it all in a relational database?

["If all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument)

There's also the fact that open-source projects can *afford* to reinvent the wheel whenever it's convenient, since you don't have the same kinds of resource constraints that commercial projects do. If you have a volunteer who's an expert at writing databases, then why not use them?

As for why we would trust the writers of revision control systems to know what they're doing.. I can't speak for other VCS's, but I'm pretty confident that [Linus Torvalds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29#History) [understands filesystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux).

#### Why do some commercial version control systems use a relational database then?

Most likely some combination of the following:

- Some developers don't *want* to write databases.
- Developers of commercial version control systems have time and resource constraints, so they can't afford to write a database when they have something close to what they want already. Also, developers are expensive, and database developers (as in, people who write databases) are probably more expensive, since most people don't have that kind of experience.
- Users of commercial version control systems are less likely to care about the overhead of setting up and running a relational database, since they already have one.
- Users of commercial version control systems are more likely to *want* a relational database backing their revision data, since this may integrate with their processes better (like backups for example).

Comment: One thing: SVN commits *are* atomic. In fact, it's a major selling point (or at least was, back when they had to convince CSV users to switch).

Comment: @delnan Oops. Fixed that.

Comment: Yikes; you say I make a lot of assumptions, and then proceed to do so as well. Really, its not possible to have two people commit to the same repo at the same time, so VCS doesn't need to worry about that? I don't assume SVN or others don't have atomic commits;but I also doubt that they only need to touch one file to record a commit,and I'm also not sure they take advantage of transaction support offered by the file system (assuming the file system the VCS is installed on even offers that). There a quite a few other assumptions you've made, but I don't think dozens of comments is the way to go

Comment: @Andy In all of the version control systems I've used, the history is linear (unless you're branching). Doing two commits at once without a branch just doesn't make sense. I suppose you could commit to two branches at the same time, but it seems like a rare situation, since even a really big company is unlikely to have multiple people committing to the same repo in the same second. For the atomic commit thing.. there's nothing magic about a relational database. If you can't do it with a file, you can't do it with a relational database (since, like a VCS database, they're backed by files).

Comment: @Andy: any version control system with a linear history model (eg, SVN, Vault, TFS) is going to take a lock the repository to do a checkin. Otherwise, you couldn't guarantee coherence.  (You could - perhaps - narrow the lock if the checkins had no overlapping paths, but I suspect that nobody does this.)  *Git* could allow multiple simultaneous commits, but committing on the same branch would result in one commit becoming the head of the branch and the other an unreachable commit, so it's advantageous to lock if you're pushing to a repo that requires new commits be children of the current head.

Comment: @delnan - Note that there is a big difference between the *theoretical* atomicity you get with `svn` where different directories in your working directory can be at different `svn` revisions and the true repository wide atomicity you get with `git` or `hg`.

Comment: @BrendanLong "Doing two commits at once without a branch just doesn't make sense." I mean two developers commiting to the same branch at the same time on the same server.  The server needs to pick who's revision to take first and then lock the repo to write the changes.  "If you can't do it with a file, you can't do it with a relational database (since, like a VCS database, they're backed by files" make a program that writes to two different files, but after the first file is changed make it blow up.  If those two files need to be updated for the commit, you're file based DB is now corrut.

Comment: @BrendanLong Now, create a program that issues two SQL commands to the db server within a transaction, but blow it up before the second command is sent.  The DB server will throw out the command and rollback the transaction.  That's the point I was trying to make.

Comment: @Andy And my point is that you can handle those exact same scenarios without a full-blown relational database. If two people commit at the exact same time, the server can do one after another. That's not a complicated feature to implement. If you want to do that with a local user, just have a lock file. When you start a commit, get a lock on the file. When you end a commit, release the lock. If you want to allows commits to multiple branches at once, use a lock file for each branch. Sure, SQLite would do this for me, but *it's not necessary*.

Comment: Similarly, implementing a basic journal isn't complicated either. (1) Write out the new commit to a file. (2) Copy the old index file. (3) Write a new index file. (4) Delete the copy of the old index file. If you fail at step 1, 2 or 4, you just need to clean up the new files you created. If you fail at step 3, you just need to copy the old index file back. Someone who understands filesystems better could probably make a much more efficient version of this, but you can always reference SQLite's source code if you need to (it's public domain).

Comment: This stuff is a *lot* easier to implement in the case of a VCS vs a relational database, because you don't need transactions (full-database locking is perfectly acceptable).

Comment: @BrendanLong Great points.  Appreciate the discussion.  Just to be clear, I think there are advantages and disadvantages to both kinds of backing stores, I don't believe there's just one correct answer.  However I was kinda suprised there seems to be only three (four if you count Vault and Vercity separately) that use SQL and the vast majority were not, that's all.

Comment: @Andy: despite both being from SourceGear, I think you should definitely count Vault and Veracity separately.

Answer (score 18):

Actually `svn` used to use BDB for repositories. This was eventually gotten rid of because it was prone to breakage.

Another VCS that currently uses a DB (SQLite) is `fossil`. It also integrates a bug tracker.

My guess at the real reason is that VCSes work with lots of files. Filesystems are just another kind of database (hierarchical, focused on CLOB/BLOB storage efficiency). Normal databases don't handle that well because there's no reason to -- filesystems already exist.

Comment: Didn't know Fossil used a database for all data storage, thanks for that info.  As far as BDB (or even SqlLite) goes, I'm not sure how that stacks up in reliabilty vs. thinks like Oracle or MSSQL.

Comment: BDB wouldn't exactly count as reliable -- like SQLite it's an in-process database. That said, I think the reliability of Oracle/MSSQL/MySQL/Postgres, depending on how you configure them, is not much different from filesystems. The main problem is that RDBMS are not built for the hierarchical & graph structures that VCSes commonly work with. And in that case, filesystems just win.

Comment: @Andy: Fossil was created by the creator of SQLite. It's not really that surprising :-)

Comment: @Andy: i'd trust SQLite _much_ more than Oracle or MSSQL.  It's no wonder that it's the most used SQL database out there, by a huge margin.  Also it's the one ported to most different architectures, each one with it's own set of challenges, making the shared code incredibly bullet-proof.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I didn't know about fossil until I went googling for different VCS to see what they used (and couldn't determine what Fossile was using).  So this is all new info to me, thanks!

Comment: @Javier I wouldn't trust Sqlite as much as MSSQL or Oracle; as Mike said the in-process part scares me, as if your app dies that could leave your DB corrupted now.  With a client / server database, the client dying aborts the transaction. Not to say its impossible for CS DBs to corrupt but i'd think its less likely than having the DB engine combined with the application.

Comment: @Andy, that's what transactions are for.  No matter at what point you kill a good DB engine, a given transaction is either committed or not.  SQLite's implementation of atomic commits (http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html) is a particularly sophisticated one.

Answer (score 11):

1. A filesystem *is* a database.  Not a relational database, of course, but most are very efficient key/value stores.  And if your access patterns are well-designed for a key-value store (eg, the git repository format), then using a database probably doesn't offer significant advantages over using the filesystem.  (In fact, it's just another layer of abstraction to get in the way.)
2. A lot of the database features are just extra baggage.  Full text search?  Does full text search make sense for source code?  Or do you need to tokenize it differently?  This also requires that you store full files at every revision, which is uncommon.  Many version control systems store deltas between revisions of the same file in order to save space, for example [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org) and [Git](http://git-scm.com) (at least, when using pack files.)
3. The cross-platform requirements make using a database more challenging.

   Most version control tools are built to run on multiple platforms.  For centralized version control tools, this only affects the server component, but it is still difficult to rely upon a single database server since Unix users cannot install Microsoft SQL Server and Windows users may be unwilling to install PostgreSQL or MySQL.  The filesystem is the least common denominator.  However, there are several tools where the server must be installed on a Windows machine, and thus require SQL Server, for example SourceGear [Vault](http://sourcegear.com/vault/) and Microsoft [Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff637362.aspx).

   Distributed version control systems make this more challenging still, since every user gets a copy of the repository.  This means that every user needs a database to put the repository into.  This implies that the software:

   1. Is limited to a subset of platforms where a particular database exists
   2. Targets a single database backend that is cross-platform (eg, SQLite).
   3. Targets a pluggable storage backend, so that one could use whatever database they wished (possibly including the filesystem).

   Most distributed version control systems, therefore, just use the filesystem.  A notable exception is SourceGear's [Veracity](http://veracity-scm.com), which can store in a SQLite database (useful for local repositories) or a relational database like SQL Server (possibly useful for a server.)  Their cloud hosted offering *may* use a non-relational storage backend like Amazon SimpleDB, but I do not know this to be true.

Comment: Just as a devil's advocate comment perhaps, most people who ask these types of "why not use a database" questions appear to mean "why not use an RDBMS?" with all the ACID compliance and other issues involved.  The fact that all file systems are already databases of their own ilk having already been discarded.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I've seen in many offerings it seems that files are "good enough" for the job, something reasonable, taking into account that at the end of the day VCSes output is also files.

There are many companies that offer a RDBMS back end with a svn/git/etc interface, so what you are asking for basically exists already.

Answer (score 5):

I would say it's because the primary data structure of a version control system is a DAG, which maps to databases very poorly.  A lot of the data is also content addressable, which also maps to databases very poorly.

Data integrity isn't the only concern of a VCS, they are also concerned with version *history* integrity, which databases aren't very good at.  In other words, when you retrieve a version, you not only need to make sure that version has no current flaws, but also that nothing in its entire history has been surreptitiously altered.

VCS are also a consumer product in addition to an enterprise product.  People use them in small, one-man hobby projects.  If you add the hassle of installing and configuring a database server, you are going to alienate much of that part of the market.  I'm guessing you don't see a lot of Vault and TFS installations at home.  It's the same reason spreadsheets and word processors don't use databases.

Also, this is more a reason for DVCS, but not using a database makes it extremely portable.  I can copy my source tree onto a thumb drive and reuse it on any machine, without having to configure a database server process.

As far as corrupting during commits, VCS uses the exact same techniques as databases to prevent simultaneous access, make transactions atomic, etc.  Corruptions in both are very rare, but they [do](https://www.google.com/search?q=team+foundation+server+corruption) [happen](https://www.google.com/search?q=vault+version+control+corruption).  For all intents and purposes, a VCS data store *is* a database.

Comment: "maps to databases very poorly" Yet Vault and TFS do just this.  "Data integrity isn't the only concern of a VCS, they are also concerned with version history integrity, which databases aren't very good at."  I fail to see how storing version history lends itself into files over a database especially since I've named products that do just that. ". Corruptions in both are very rare, but they do happen."  None of those results in the first page talk about the Vault server database being corrupt.  The one link that even talks about the Vault software the problem is the WC got corrupted.

Comment: "For all intents and purposes, a VCS data store is a database."  Well... that's my point.  Why not just stick the data in a real database system instead of rolling your own?

Comment: @Andy Yes, it's a database, but not all databases are substitutable for one another. Each database has a certain view on the world (for example, SQL DBs basically implement the relational model). As this answer details, the data a VCS stores and the way that data is used doesn't fit the relational model. I'm not sure if some NoSQL db does better, but they're rather new and are yet to prove their superiority (I recall reports of serious integrity issues for some). And then there are all the other issues atop of that.

Comment: DAGs are only used in DVCS (unless you consider a linear history an exceptionally simple DAG, which it is, but that's not really a helpful abstraction.)  When your history is linear, with monotonically increasing changesets, a SQL database makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Monotonically increasing version numbers don't make a lot of sense for VCSes. I've used a fair number of them, and the ones with centralized version numbers (CVS & SVN being the 2 I'm most familiar with) tend to be a pain to merge with. And even those use DAGs when they attempt to do merging. Just because their storage representation isn't based around it doesn't mean it isn't used.

Comment: How does CVS build a graph when it does a merge?  It doesn't even have changesets, after all.  (And yes, a three-way merge is, I guess, pedantically a "DAG" containing three files.  But again, that's not really a useful description.)

Comment: @EdwardThomson A version control system without branches and merging does not really count as real version control system these days, and as soon as you have branch, and you merge changes back... DAG!

Comment: @hyde: No, in a DVCS model, branches occur at the entire repository level.  In a (typical) centralized version control model, history is a line and branches and merges occur *in* the repository.  Not *on* the repository.  History is not a DAG in, say, Subversion or CVS, regardless of their ability to branch and merge. http://www.ericsink.com/entries/dvcs_dag_1.html  Like I said, you could call a three-way merge "building a DAG", but that would pretty well obfuscate what DAG means in a history model in a distributed system.

Comment: @Andy using a filesystem isn't rolling your own database any more than creating tables within an RDBMS is.  You have to create a data structure somewhere, and if that data structure is tree-based, the file system fits better than a typical RDBMS anyway.  Point being: a relational database structure needs creating just as much as the file system structure, there's no 'savings' in effort either way.

Answer (score 2):

- **Better disaster recovery** (worst case scenario: we'll parse it by eye, like in the old times)
- Making tracking and debugging such disasters, possibly caused by faults in the VCS system, easier.
- Lowering the number of dependencies. (let's not forget one of those systems is handling *the* kernel, and the other was supposed to)
- A text-editor is ***always*** available. (MS SQL Server licenses... not so much)

Comment: This answer is just bad.  The only really true point is lowering the number of dependencies.  Both backing systems should be on par as you should be doing proper backups, debugging DB applications is no more difficult than debugging applications that write files, and text editor is always available?  I don't even know what your point is there, as the VCS isn't itself going to use a text editor, and there ARE other DB servers out there (Sqlite, Postgre, MySql, etc.) so that if you WANTED a db backed solution lack of a db server shouldn't be a factor.

Comment: @Andy ***...the programmers*** are going to use to use a text editor. You know, text editing is still available as a secondary function even in your favourite IDE.

Comment: @Andy ***`sqlite` is the only possible alternative*** to text files, given the vast amount of distributed scenarios modern DVCS serve. (idk, maybe you might have missed the "distributed" part of DVCS) Anything else would be too cumbersome (configuration + firewalling + license) or even silly to be **distributed**. Then again doing a worst case scenario postmortem to an sqlite might prove hard.

Comment: @ZJR: I don't think the original question *ever* specified distributed version control, it asked about version control systems in general.  Further, your text editor argument is a little flat, since plenty of systems don't store just flat text files.  Even git has plenty of binary file formats (loose objects, pack files, etc) that render your text editor useless.

Comment: @ZJR How is editing code in a text editor relevent to the backing store of a VCS?  Are you suggesting manually editing, say SVN's database?  Also my question is not limited to DVCS, so I don't know why you're harping on it.

Comment: @Andy text editors are a beauty of Git -- `cat .git/logs/refs/heads/master` is simple and easy.  Most other functionality is easily achieved this way as well.  Remember that modern distributed version control is not server-based but hosted on every single box doing development.  Even that's unfair: many are being used by authors and artists as well.

Comment: @mikebabcock: aside from refs and the reflog, there's really not much that's usefully `cat`able in a git repo.  The index is binary, the objects are (at best) deflated or (at worst) stuck in a packfile.  So sure, you can edit a ref with a text editor, but that's about it.

Comment: I beg to differ.  http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/git/directory.htm is a good start.

Comment: @mikebabcock that link didn't really elucidate.  I don't think `COMMIT_EDITMSG` is really part of the repository format, so I'm not sure what files you're talking about.

Comment: @mikebabcock Sorry, that sounded sort of snarky and wasn't meant to.  My point is that without any of the binary files (all the objects), you don't have a repo.

Answer (score 1):

[Fossil](http://fossil-scm.org/) is an excellent Distributed Version Control System (DVCS) and uses SQLite for storage, no plain-text files.

I really like that it has integrated: bug tracking, Wiki and that it is really distributed. I mean you can really work offline and fix bugs.

Fossil uses Sqlite as it's application file format.
In the [keynote at PgCon](https://youtu.be/ZvmMzI0X7fE?t=5m35s) Dr. Richard Hipp explains what are the advantages of using sqlite as an Application File System, and makes a pretty convincing argument of the benefits of using a database as filesystem.

> The second main topic was that SQLite should be seen as an application file format—an alternative to inventing own file formats or using ZIPped XMLs. The statement “SQLite is not a replacement for PostgreSQL. SQLite is a replacement for fopen()” nails that (slide 21). Finally, Richard put a lot of emphasis on that fact that SQLite takes care of your data (crash safe, ACID) [use-the-index.com](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2012-11/pgconfeu2012-summary)

Now [Dr. Hipp](http://fossil-scm.org/xfer/doc/trunk/www/theory1.wiki) has addressed the concerns on saving code on a database

- Why is Fossil based on SQLite instead of a distributed NoSQL database?

> Fossil is not based on SQLite. The current implementation of Fossil uses SQLite as a local store for the content of the distributed database and as a cache for meta-information about the distributed database that is precomputed for quick and easy presentation. But the use of SQLite in this role is an implementation detail and is not fundamental to the design. Some future version of Fossil might do away with SQLite and substitute a pile-of-files or a key/value database in place of SQLite. (Actually, that is very unlikely to happen since SQLite works amazingly well in its current role, but the point is that omitting SQLite from Fossil is a theoretical possibility.)